# Finding the height of a binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the folloing "height" function which returns the height of a tree. When I try to use it, however, I get this exception. How can I fix it? I also have the function "isBalancedTree" which checks if a given tree is balanced.

```
data Tree = Node Tree Int Tree | Leaf Int deriving Show

height :: Tree -> Integer
height (Node left x right) = 1 + max (height left) (height right)

isBalancedTree :: Tree -> Bool
isBalancedTree (Node left x right) = 
    let diff = abs (height left - height right) in
    diff <= 1 && isBalancedTree left && isBalancedTree right
```

*Main> height (Node (Node (Leaf 3) 4 (Leaf 2)) 5 (Node (Leaf 4) 7 (Leaf 6)))

*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function height

Comment: What if `isBalanced` or `height` gets a `Leaf`?

Comment: Turn on warnings with `-Wall`! The compiler will then point out the missing cases in your pattern matching. Strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive implementation of `height` is nice, but you have forgotten the base case of a single leaf:

```
height (Leaf _) = 1
```

This is the missing pattern that the exception is complaining about. The same applies to your second function `isBalanced` - you need a case for a `Leaf`, too:

```
isBalanced (Leaf _) = True -- assuming a single-leaf tree is trivially balanced
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the same exception for my second function. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @u23d7 The problem with the second function is exactly the same. I updated the answer.